# Python code that explicitly identifies a pd.dataframe column as TIMESTAMP is having the datetime converted to an int and a long series of numbers

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have python code that is writing to Bigquery.

I have a function that takes a pd.dataframe and explicitly converts a dataframe column that is datetime64[ns] to TIMESTAMP but when the table that is examined in BigQuery, the TIMESTAMP has been converted to Integer and is a large number. Here is the Function:

```
def write_dataframe_to_bigquery2(dataframe, project_id, dataset_id, table_id):
    # Convert the Pandas DataFrame to a PyArrow Table
    table = pa.Table.from_pandas(dataframe)

    # Write the PyArrow Table to a Parquet file
    pq.write_table(table, 'temp.parquet')

    # Create a BigQuery client
    client = bigquery.Client(project=project_id)
    
    schema = []
    for column in df_merged_gcp.columns:
        if df_merged_gcp[column].dtype == 'datetime64[ns]':
            schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField(column, 'TIMESTAMP'))
        elif df_merged_gcp[column].dtype == 'int64':
            schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField(column, 'INTEGER'))
        else:
            schema.append(bigquery.SchemaField(column, 'STRING'))

    # Set the table reference
    table_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id).table(table_id)

    # Delete the existing table if it already exists
    if client.get_table(table_ref):
        client.delete_table(table_ref)

    # Create the BigQuery table from the Parquet file
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
        autodetect=False,
        source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.PARQUET
        )
    with open('temp.parquet', 'rb') as source_file:
        job = client.load_table_from_file(source_file, table_ref, job_config=job_config)

    job.result()  # Wait for the job to complete

    print(f"Dataframe overwritten to BigQuery table: {project_id}.{dataset_id}.{table_id}")

    # Clean up temporary Parquet file
    os.remove('temp.parquet')
```

The first column in the dataframe is a datetime (ex. 2023-11-14 08:11:00).
When examined in GCP Bigquery, the value is an INTEGER (ex. 1699821479000000000).

How do I have my python code correctly write to GCP a TIMESTAMP with a valid TIMESTAMP?

Thank you for any assistance this community can provide.

I have walked through the code and verified that the schema correctly identifies the datetime column as TIMESTAMP.